# Dynamically Set Row AutoFit

Tags: excel, vba

I work with an excel sheet with Slicers built it to filter data.  I would like to dynamically set the row height.  Is there an easy VBA to use?  I am currently trying

```
'AutoFit One Row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Rows("V24:V400").Rows.AutoFit
```

Comment: What is not working about what you are trying? And please define "dynamically" (i.e. - your row count will be dynamic? Or the row height?

Comment: Thank you!  I'd like the row height to be dynamic because the row count will be dynamic, if that makes sense.  So if I use my filter, Row K might not have a status update but when I filter, Row K might have a status update with 500 characters.  I am going to try your loop suggestion.  Thanks again!

Comment: That was not my suggestion. Row Height may also be affected by column width. Also, look into Wrap-Text. Without wrap-text, I think row height will always default to 15 on `AutoFit`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the first row you use, you can dynamically define the last row:

```
Dim LR as Long 'LR = Last Row
With Sheets("NAME")
    LR = .Cell( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'cells(row, col) means this is row 1 contigent
End With
```

Then in your code you can use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Range(Rows("24"),Rows(LR)).EntireRow.AutoFit
```

---

If you're talking about the height specifically, you can set a variable for the rowheight using a loop per row, such as:

```
Dim i as Long, j as Integer
j = "" 'Define i how you want.  You can make it an if statement or select case for some set units
For i = 24 to 400
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet9").Rows(i).RowsHeight = j
Next i
```